# Why oozie submits shell action to yarn?

Tags: hadoop, scheduler, hadoop-yarn, oozie, hadoop2

I am recently learning oozie. I little curious about shell action. I am executing shell action which contains shell command like

```
hadoop jar <jarPath> <FQCN>
```

While running this action there are two yarn jobs running which are

1. one for hadoop job
2. one for shell action

I dont understand why shell action needs yarn for execution. I also tried email action. It executes without yarn resources.

Comment: Email just requires an API call, it does not consume RAM or CPU or disk I/O - and just a little bit of network I/O. And indeed it is the **only** "action" that is executed inside the Oozie server. Everything else is offloaded to YARN. That's a core design choice. Remember that Yahoo! created Oozie to run **raw MapReduce** jobs; the rest (java, shell, pig, hive, distcp...) has been added as an afterthought, using a "launcher" job with just 1 Map as a proxy.

Comment: With just a bit of Googling: *"A **fundamental design principle** in Oozie is that the Oozie server never runs user code other than the execution of the workflow itself. This ensures better service stability by isolating user code away from Oozie’s code. The Oozie server is also **stateless** and the launcher job makes it possible for it to stay that way. "* https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/apache-oozie/9781449369910/ch04.html

Answer (score 2):

To answer this question, the difference is between

1. running a shell script independently(.sh file or from CLI)
2. running a shell action as a part of an oozie workflow.(shell script in an oozie shell action)

The first case is very obvious.

In the second case, oozie launches the shell script via YARN(is the resource negotiator )to run your shell script on the cluster where oozie is installed and runs MR jobs internally to launch the shell action. So the shell script runs as a YARN application internally.  The logs of the oozie workflow shows the way the shell action is launched in oozie.